# Play Console: Что находится во вкладке Управление релизом >> Отчет о тестировании >> Сбои?

Tags: google-play-console

Что находится во вкладке Управление релизом >> Отчет о тестировании >> Сбои Play Console? Там в результатах тестирования 10 устройств: информация о каждом и видео где кто-то нажимает на все кнопки подряд. Так кто тестировал мое приложение? Бот?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из [этой](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=ru) и [этой](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/pre-launch-crash-reports?hl=ru) ссылок следует, что

> тестирование приложения на различных устройствах выполняется автоматически и выявляет проблемы с дизайном, диагностирует сбои, обнаруживает уязвимости и другие проблемы.

Принцип тестирования
После загрузки и публикации альфа- или бета-версии APK-файла приложение запускается на тестовых устройствах и сканируется в течение нескольких минут. При этом в приложении автоматически выполняются такие действия, как ввод текста, нажатие и пролистывание.

Результаты проверки появляются в разделе Отчет о тестировании Play Console.

Примечания:

- Тестовые устройства отбираются по ряду критериев: популярности, частоте возникновения сбоев, разрешению экрана, производителю, операционной системе и т. д.
- Отчет о тестировании формируется по результатам анализа, выполненного в [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/)